# Example of $\int_{\Omega}(f+g)d\mu\ne\int_{\Omega}fd\mu+\int_{\Omega}gd\mu$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let $\left (\Omega,\mathcal{F},\nu \right )$ be a measure space,$f$ and $g$ be two extended real-valued $\mathcal{F-}$measurable functions on $\Omega$.

When $f\ge 0$ and $g\ge0$,obviously, $\int_{\Omega}(f+g)d\nu=\int_{\Omega}fd\nu+\int_{\Omega}gd\nu.$

Are there some counterexamples such that $$\int_{\Omega}(f+g)d\nu\in\mathbb{\overline{R}},\int_{\Omega}fd\nu\in\mathbb{\overline{R}},\int_{\Omega}gd\nu\in\mathbb{\overline{R}},\mathbb{\overline{R}}:=\left [ -\infty,\infty \right ].$$

but $\int_{\Omega}(f+g)d\nu\ne\int_{\Omega}fd\nu+\int_{\Omega}gd\nu?$

I have an idea:

Let $\Omega=[0,\infty),\mathcal{F}=\mathcal{M}_{L} \cap[0,\infty)$,$\nu=\mu_L|_{\Omega}.$
where $\mathcal{M}_{L}$ is the Lebesgue $\sigma-$algebra subsets of $\mathbb{R},\mu_L$ is the Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb{R}.$
$$f=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}n\mathbf{1}_{A_n},A_{n}=\left [n-1,  n\right ),$$ $$g=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}-n\mathbf{1}_{A_n},A_{n}=\left [n-1,  n\right ).$$

Comment: Your example is fine if there is no requirement that $\int_{\Omega}fd\mu+\int_{\Omega}gd\mu$ is defined.

Answer (score 1):

Your example is just fine as is:

Given:

$ f = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} n \chi_{A_n} $

$ g = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (-n) \chi_{A_n} $

where $ \chi_{A_n} $ is the characteristic function (or indicator function) of the set $ A_n $ and $ A_n = [n-1, n) $.

For any $ x $ in $ A_n $, $ f(x) = n $ and $ g(x) = -n $. Thus, $ f(x) + g(x) = 0 $ for all $ x $ in $ Ω $ (because every $ x $ belongs to some $ A_n $).

Calculating the integrals:

1. $ \int_{Ω} (f + g) dμ $:

Since $ f(x) + g(x) = 0 $ for all $ x $, the integral is just 0.

2. $ \int_{Ω} f dμ $:

$ \int_{Ω} f dμ = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} n \mu(A_n) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} n $

(since the measure of $ A_n $ is 1 for each $ n $).

Due to divergency $ \int_{Ω} f dμ = \infty $.

3. $ \int_{Ω} g dμ $:

$ \int_{Ω} g dμ = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (-n) \mu(A_n) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (-n) $

This is the negative of the series for $ f $ and hence $ \int_{Ω} g dμ = -\infty $.

Finally, adding the integrals of $ f $ and $ g $, we get:

$ \int_{Ω} f dμ + \int_{Ω} g dμ = \infty + (-\infty) = \text{undefined} $

This result is not the same as the integral of $ f+g $, which is 0. Thus, your example indeed serves as a counterexample to the equation:

$ \int_{Ω} (f + g) dμ \neq \int_{Ω} f dμ + \int_{Ω} g dμ $

when integrating extended real-valued measurable functions.

Therefore, your idea is proper.

Answer (score 1):

Let $\left (\Omega,\mathcal{F},\mu \right )$ be a measure space, and let $f,g : \Omega \to
[-\infty, +\infty]$ be measurable. The equality
$$\int_{\Omega}(f+g)d\mu=\int_{\Omega}fd\mu+\int_{\Omega}gd\mu$$
does not always hold: we have to make an additional requirement that $f,g \geq 0$, or equivalently, $f,g\leq 0$.

Your example is fine. In your example, $\int_{\Omega}(f+g)d\mu=0$, $\int_{\Omega}fd\mu=+\infty$,$\int_{\Omega}gd\mu=-\infty$, but $\infty-\infty$ is undefined.